# can Arduino IDE link to other libs / files in other directories?

Tags: arduino-ide

can Arduino IDE point to a file in another directory? If yes how?
With my code

```
../../main.h
```

the compile fails.

Error:

```
In file included from D:\Eigene Dateien\Entwicklung\SIGNALDuino_MR\src\arduino-ide\SIGNALDuino\SIGNALDuino.ino:1:0:

main.h:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

 ../../main.h

 ^

exit status 1
expected unqualified-id before '.' token
```

--------------- structure ------------------

```
TEST
  |--main.h
  |-----Ordner 1
             |-----Ordner 3
                       |--files.h
  |-----Ordner 2
             |-----Ordner 4
```

Comment: `#include "../../main.h"`

Comment: No it doesn't work. The file exists in the directory (2 times back in the structure)

 :-( `#include "../../main.h"

                        ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
../../main.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: I  didn't expect it to work. the Arduino IDE builds the sketch in a temporary folder, not in the sketch folder. but to include the #iinclude directive is the only possible syntax

Comment: But he should read the file from there :-( No absolute position should be given. The file is 2 levels up.

Comment: it is not two levels up from the temporary folder

Comment: to avoid misunderstandings, it is a path \ src \ which has the first main.h. This contains the structure \ arduino-ide \ project \ where the main.h file is located. This should call the "first" main.h.

Comment: The answer is in the wrong direction. The user wants from MCUa.ino in TimerLib.h.

But my plan is backwards. Jump back directories. Based on the example, from TimerLib.h to MCUa.ino

Comment: it is the same question as yours. include in sketch something on relative path

Comment: it does not work `#include ../../main.h` or  `#include "../../main.h"`

Comment: read the answer to the other question.